# SWT Section - can't set title background gradient

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface, sections

I'm using a `FormToolkit` to create a `Section`.

Why doesn't the `setTitleBarGradientBackground` API have any effect on the coloring of the title bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug report [here (Bug 213193)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213193). Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can expect this to be fixed any time soon...

> `Section#setTitleBarBackground` is working now - sets the top color of the section background gradient like in RCP.
>
> `Section#setTitleBarGradientBackground` sets a color (`Section#COLOR_GBG`) that is never used in Section class??!!
>
> `Section#setTitleBarBorderColor` - has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting `Section` source code shows, that the code is implemented in the following way:

```
/**
 * Sets the color of the title bar gradient background when TITLE_BAR style
 * is used. This color is used at the height where title controls end
 * (toggle, tool bar).
 * 
 * @param color
 *            the title bar gradient background
 */
public void setTitleBarGradientBackground(Color color) {
    putTitleBarColor(COLOR_GBG, color);
}
```

But if you take a look at `Section#onPaint(PaintEvent e)` you won't find any usage of `COLOR_GBG`.